# How is "戚" Being Used as a Standalone Verb to Mean "Feel"?

Tags: meaning

Samples from the Internet:

[1)](https://www.ntpu.edu.tw/admin/a9/org/a9-5/files/announce/20150527165203.PDF) 我對學校老師的專業程度戚到滿意。

[2)](https://www.jiankang.com/ask/133082690.shtml) 膝关节经常戚到有些酸软

[3)](https://www3.ha.org.hk/cph/imh/doc/information/psychiatrists/L21.pdf) 如果你因此戚到不開心或困擾

Clearly, "戚" is being used as a verb to mean "feel".  But the [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/621A.htm) definition doesn't include any instances where it can be used as a verb, and the only verb definitions I can find in other dictionaries are for ancient classical meanings ("to feel anxiety") which don't really fit here, in particular within the positive context in 1). Is this use of "戚" dialetical, i.e. representing a Cantonese or Taiwanese usage?

Comment: You use the wrong word. It should be 感.

Answer (score 4):

It's an artifact of an OCR misreading 感 as 戚.  This is causing Google et al to hit on 戚到 when it's supposed to be 感到 as young99 notes in his comment.

I originally encountered the "usage" in an online book that was in text format, but that must have been scanned in and OCR'd using a similar engine. Hence the typo.  Will leave this question here so that anyone else getting tripped up by this won't be confused by it.  Thanks to young99 for helping me think through this.

Comment: I will once the system lets me- there's apparently a two day waiting period

Answer (score -2):

“于我心有戚戚焉”。戚 是古语用法，现在很少会用到。现在一般会用 觉着，感觉 等。